# Displaying Image dynamically in the asp.net webpage

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, webforms

I want to display images in my website developed in asp.net(web form) dynamically. Like I have created a a page in admin section where I am uploading the image and the uploded image save in the folder and its path save in the database. Now uploading and edit on image is done by me. I want to display in my page in which I want to 4 images in a row. So what will be the control i need to use. or is there any other idea i can go for creating this task.

I am thanking you so for you ideas

Comment: show us some code amar

Comment: Actually Sir, Now I am displaying image statically like below

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataList or DataRepeater or any data control to Display Image. Its depend on requirement.

If you want show images on client side then use DataRepeater.

For display images in Datalist :
http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/how-to-display-images-in-datalist-control-using-Asp-Net-with-C-Sharp-1037.aspx

Display images in Repeater :
http://ravisatyadarshi.wordpress.com/2012/11/17/how-to-display-an-image-gallery-using-repeater-in-asp-net/

Answer (score 0):

You can use image control..

like,
e.g.-
 Image1.ImageUrl = "~/uploads/"+imgstr+"";

here imgstr i variable in which you are getting image path from db